# how to add one more elsif into this function?

Tags: python, django

I have this code,

```
def domain(self):
    long_url = urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url else "be kind to one another"
    return long_url.split('.', 1)[1] if long_url.split('.', 1)[0] == 'www' else long_url
```

it prints the domain name of url if there's url, otherwise it prints "be kind to one another" thing is I now have video field. so I can do self.video. I tried to write "video" if there's self.video. But I'm keep failing. can you please help me?

Comment: Writing in a single line does not make things more efficient. You should just write the new `self.video` in `if-elif-else` blocks. This also makes it easier to read

Comment: @Obsidian hmm I just tried it but I couldn't do it...can you show me how if you know??

Comment: What is `self.video`? How do you plan to use it? It would be easier if you add one more line to your code above with this information

Comment: @Obsidian I have video field like this,  video = EmbedVideoField(verbose_name='video') 
so I'm trying to put word "video" if it's self.video

Comment: You mean `if self.video: long_url = "video"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you should chain `if ... else`. It makes the code hard to read. But as a point about the language, yes it can be chained, associating left to right, like so:

```
>>> 'a' if 1 else 'b' if 1 else 'c'
'a'
>>> 'a' if 0 else 'b' if 1 else 'c'
'b'
>>> 'a' if 0 else 'b' if 0 else 'c'
'c'
```

Likewise

```
long_url = ('video' if self.video
            else urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url
            else "be kind to one another")
```

Is this what you want?